# Impute categorical missing values in scikit-learn using specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

i have data set for patients ,i want to handle missing value for  these data, it contain both numerical and text, the idea that i want to handle based on subject id. Not replace based on columns only 
the data set looks like this

```
 subject_id     time      heart_rate      blood_pressure    urine_color 
   1             1.10          23              60                red
   1              2                            40                
   2             3             60              80              
   2             4                                            dark yellow
```

i want to replace text data with most frequent patient's data and numeric with mean values for patient also, to be like this

```
 subject_id     time      heart_rate      blood_pressure    urine_color 
   1             1.10          23              60                red
   1              2            23              40                red
   2             3             60              80              dark yellow 
   2             4             60              80              dark yellow
```

any one can help in this , all impute method i search about , use most frequent in column , or statistical analysis for the whole column

Comment: what if there are no values for heart_rate for particular subject_id?

Comment: it will not make impute, or i will make another step that impute based on whole column after this step .
but the idea it will be small amount of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with custom function for `mean` with numeric columns and `mode` for categoricals columns and replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x.mode().iat[0]
```

Alternative if possible all `NaN`s values for categorical columns per group:

```
f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else next(iter(x.mode()), None)
```

---

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['subject_id'])
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df.groupby('subject_id')[cols].transform(f))
print (df)
   subject_id time  heart_rate  blood_pressure  urine_color
0           1  1.1          23              60          red
1           1    2          23              40          red
2           2    3          60              80  dark yellow
3           2    4          60              80  dark yellow
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your concern , but if you don't mind to explain the first two lines of your answer

Comment: @Nora - Just add some info to answer, if something is necessary explain more let me know

Comment: really  thank you, but when it make the transform step it give me the following error (IndexError: ('index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0')

Comment: @Nora - Do you try `f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else next(iter(x.mode()), None)` ? It seems some only NaNs per group

Comment: yes , there is some NaN values per group. you mean try the other one?

Comment: @Nora - yes, instead `f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x.mode().iat[0]` use `f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else next(iter(x.mode()), None)`

Comment: when i use your code without grouping to handle the other missing values like this    ** f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else next(iter(x.mode()), None)
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(df[cols].transform(f))** it gives me this error "ValueError: transforms cannot produce aggregated results" (

Comment: @Nora - Are data confidental?

Comment: @Nora - Is possible send me data to my email from my profile? Only run code for email.

Comment: @Nora - Super, only one thing - please test if raise error sample data sent to me.